# Spring + RMI how to limit concurrent connection from client to server

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, spring-security

Hi i work on java project with spring framework and implement client-server side with Spring RMI is there anyway to limit concurrent client call to server? i try google around and found that spring provide Security container package that can limit number of concurrent per authenticated user which i don't thik it is what i look for

here is server-side config provided in spring's website i wonder if i could config it to limit concurrent connection ?

```
<bean id="checkingAccountService"
    class="org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerServiceExporter">
  <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.foo.CheckingAccountService"/>
  <property name="service">
     <bean class="com.foo.SimpleCheckingAccountService"/>
  </property>
</bean>
```

thx for your reply

Comment: that would generally be handled at the server-config level by restricting the number of request-handler threads available.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer Affe? did you mean configuration in spring's .xml file,in spring site there provide and examlple that you can config serviceInterface and service value but there are no config for request-handler thread(i use org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter)

Comment: on what?  tomcat?  glassfish?  jboss?  the number of http threads is configurable, anything in excess of that sits in a queue until a thread is free or the request times out.  If it's also serving other requests and you want to limit the concurrency of just that service you'll probably need to use your own worker pool.